# Update DropdownList dynamically within a Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

There is an issue I have not been able to solve which is where there is an 'Add Item' button on a form. When clicked this opens a Modal window which contains two dropdown lists. The first dropdown list is prepopulated with a set of items and based on this selection, the 2nd dropdown box ideally needs to update with its own set of items.

**This is the first Dropdown List which contains the Type**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLType" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LoadSubTypes" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Automobile">Automobile</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Aeroplane">Aeroplane</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Boat">Boat</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**This is the second Dropdown List which currently sits empty until a selection is made from the first dropdown list.**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLSubType" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**With the first DDL where there is an OnSelectedIndexChange, this is the code behind.**

```
protected void LoadSubTypes(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string strSubTypeList = "";
    switch (DDLType.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "Automobile":
            strSubTypeList = "Car#Motorbike#Scooter";
            break;
        case "Aeroplane":
            strSubTypeList = "Commercial#Private";
            break;
        case "Boat":
            strSubTypeList = "Boat#Jetski";
            break;
    }

    StringBuilder sbSubTypes = new StringBuilder();
    Char delimiter = '#';
    String[] substrings = strSubTypeList.Split(delimiter);
    foreach (var substring in substrings)
    {
        DDLSubType.DataTextField = substring;
        DDLSubType.DataValueField = substring;
        DDLSubType.DataBind();
    } }
```

Normally this type of setup works well for me, but the only difference this time is I have them loaded into a Modal. What happens when I make a selection from the DDL is that the modal closes and causes the postback. This resets any values that were then changed dynamically.

My ideal behavior here is that when a selection is made on the first DDL, the 2nd DDL updates within the modal and do not close.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the **free** ASP.net Ajax Control toolkit, specifically the [CascadingDropdown](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/CascadingDropDown)  control.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that when I select an item from a dropdown list, then its relevent options will be shown on the next dropdown. You will have to use jquery ajax(it will be more easy). 
When an item is selected from a dropdown, its **value** will be passed using ajax, which will without refreshing your page get your dropdown.
e.g.

```
<select class="form-control" id="Departments" ><option value="">-Select Department-</option>
    <option value="17">No Department</option>
    <option value="19">Men</option>
    <option value="1018">Danial</option>
    </select>
```

JavaScript with jquery:

```
$("#Departments").change(function () {
    var deptId = $(this).select("option:selected").val();

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/Categories/M_Level2/" + deptId
    }).done(function (categories) 
{
    $("#category").html(categories);                             
});
```

In url, **Categories** is the controller and M_Level2 is the action that is getting a value **deptId** and on that basis returning a PartialView and then adding it on **#category**

Comment: Hi Ahmed, are you able to clarify with further examples of how to implement this? I think i understand what is happening, but cannot produce the desired result with what you have posted.

Comment: Stephen you are using ASP.NET MVC 4. And the thing that i implemented, is in ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: The question looks like pure WebForms to me. Not sure how an MVC answer is relevant (obviously, they can be mixed, but you can't assume that from what's shown).